# Is the semantics for this sqlite JOIN query right?

Tags: android-sqlite

```
SELECT *
FROM VibeComment
JOIN UsersInfo
    ON VibeComment.user_phone_number = UsersInfo.phone_number
WHERE vibeID = '2' AND
      type = 'specific'
```

It returns a null cursor the database contains data.

Comment: To which tables do the `vibeID` and `type`columns belong?

Comment: Hey Tim, sorry i delayed getting back, they belong to the VibeComent table

Comment: What are the types of `vibeID` and `type` ?